# pytest basics. Running tests in a directory

Tags: python, pytest

I create a simple new project with a new virtualenv. `requirements.txt` just has `pytest` and that's it.

```
.
├── requirements.txt
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── sample_tests.py
```

`sample_tests.py`:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.unit
def test_a():
    assert 1 + 1 == 2
```

If I run pytest with the python test file name, it works fine:

```
vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/pytestdemo pytest tests/sample_tests.py
```

However, none of the following invocations work. All of them fail to see the test and output `collected 0 items` and `no tests ran`:

```
vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/pytestdemo pytest tests
vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/pytestdemo pytest tests/
vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/pytestdemo pytest

vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/pytestdemo python -m pytest tests
vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/pytestdemo python -m pytest tests/
vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/pytestdemo python -m pytest
```

In this simple scenario I just have one test file and one test, but in my real application, I have many tests, and I want a simple invocation to run all of them. I've narrowed down my scenario to this super simple isolated example and I'd like to get very basic test invocation to work.

I've poured through the docs and getting started guides. I've tried using (and not using) a custom `pytest.ini`. Obviously, I tried invoking by both `pytest` and by `python -m pytest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `pytest` discovers tests only in files named `test_*.py` or `*_test.py`, from [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery). That's why it finds tests in your file when you directly pass file name as an argument:

```
vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/pytestdemo pytest tests/sample_tests.py
```

And fails to find them in other invocations. So, your options are:

1. Change file name to fit one of default collection patterns.
2. [Change standard test discovery.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)